# Allos matplotlib fmt value override any other keyword parameters

Tags: python, matplotlib

Say I have a call to `matplotlib.pyplot.plt` that looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = x**2

plt.plot(x, y, 'k--', color=[1, 0, 0])
```

The output will be a red dashed line, even though I have specified a *black* dashed line in the `fmt` arg. This makes sense, as the matplotlib documentation explicitly says:

> When conflicting with fmt, keyword arguments take precedence.

Is there any tricky way to reverse this behavior, though? I want `fmt` to take precedence over the `color` parameter.

Edit:

Why I want to do this...

I have a function

`plotStuff(dataDirs, formats=None)`

where `dataDirs` is a list of directory names containing some data. the function ultimately plots `len(dataDirs)` lines. Each line will be colored based on a `colors` array which is internal to the function. However, I'd like the user to be able to override this with the optional `formats` argument (an array of strings, of length `len(dataDirs)`).

I could ask whether or not the optional argument `formats` was passed, and if so, ignore `colors`. But, that won't work, because if the formats passed by the user happen to only contain a `linestyle` (like `'--'`), and no color (like `'k--'`), then the color would be chosen from the matplotlib color cycle which I don't want.

I could go through the annoying task of determining if the strings in the `formats` array contains a color, but surely there's a simpler way.

Comment: Can you explain why do you have to have both arguments? maybe there's a better and more elegant solution to your problem.

Comment: @anishtain4 edited

Comment: Doesn't it work to change the color cycle to what you want?
https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html#colors-color-cycles-and-color-maps

Comment: @anishtain4 For further reasons that would be unnecessary and besides the point for this question, I cannot do that either. In short, there will be certain lines that need to be the same color (data is broken up among different files, and my loop structure doesn't allow simply concatenating the data arrays, which would not be trivial to change)

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. To me it seems you just need to not use the `fmt` at all and set the color to whatever it needs to be through the `color` alone; i.e. if the user supplies `color` use that, else use your custom color instead.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Then the user cannot specify the linestyle. Sure, I could make both the color and linestyle an input argument, but that's considerably more cumbersome for the user

Comment: At one point you will need to decide: Do you want convenience for the user or for the programmer? In the former case, the answer below shows you what to do. In the latter case, letting your function simply take the keyword arguments and pass them to `plot` would be easiest. Depends on how many users you have and how much of a challenge it is for them to type two arguments with clear structure, compared to one argument which is rather intransparent.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I don't think there is a tricky way to reverse this behavior because it is [coded as so](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_base.py#L287):

1. `fmt` is processed and put in `kw`:

   ```
   def _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs):
       ret = []
       if len(tup) > 1 and isinstance(tup[-1], str):
           linestyle, marker, color = _process_plot_format(tup[-1])
           tup = tup[:-1]
       elif len(tup) == 3:
           raise ValueError('third arg must be a format string')
       else:
           linestyle, marker, color = None, None, None

       ...

       kw = {}
       for k, v in zip(('linestyle', 'marker', 'color'),
                       (linestyle, marker, color)):
           if v is not None:
               kw[k] = v
   ```
2. Use `kw` and `kwargs` to call `_makeline`:

   ```
       if self.command == 'plot':
           func = self._makeline
       else:
           kw['closed'] = kwargs.get('closed', True)
           func = self._makefill

       ...

       for j in range(max(ncx, ncy)):
           seg = func(x[:, j % ncx], y[:, j % ncy], kw, kwargs)
           ret.append(seg)
       return ret
   ```
3. `kwargs` overwrite `kw` in `_makeline`:

   ```
   def _makeline(self, x, y, kw, kwargs):
       kw = {**kw, **kwargs}  # Don't modify the original kw.
       default_dict = self._getdefaults(None, kw)
       self._setdefaults(default_dict, kw)
       seg = mlines.Line2D(x, y, **kw)
       return seg
   ```

It seems that the best way is to "go through the annoying task of determining if the strings in the formats array contains a color" potentially the same way as [matplotlib does](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_base.py#L109-L113).